# Modulation and Coding Scheme scaling

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11

I have 2 of the same client devices using 802.11ax WiFi technology. One is configured to use 2 spatial streams and the other has 3. When they are connected to the access point at range (600ft or more), both devices show that they are using just 1 spatial stream (due to proper MCS scaling).

Even though they are both using just 1 spatial stream, the device with 3 spatial streams is still able to show higher throughput than the device with 2 spatial streams. Can anyone supply a good explanation of why this is? I have not been able to find a good article on this.

Comment: Can you provide specific information about each adapter?

Comment: What kind of specific information are you inquiring about?

Comment: The type of information that can identify the adapter, research it, and provide a smart intelligent answer to your question

Comment: The wireless antennas are 2x2 and 3x3 802.11ax capable of 80Mhz. Wireless chip is Broadcom, model is BCM4360. Please let me know what other specific information to provide and I will do my best to provide it.